# Modifying the tabBarBadge color in react native bottom tab navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have a react-native app that uses `createBottomTabNavigator` for navigation. I have set custom icons for the 2 tabs that comprise the navigator and I have added badges to them using `navigation.setOptions` like so:

```
navigation.setOptions({ tabBarBadge: 1 }) // sample value
```

This works fine as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IygzW.png). However, now I want to modify that red-ish colour of the badge to an arbitrary one. Following the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#tabbarbadgestyle), I have tried changing the colour like so:

```
navigation.setOptions({ tabBarBadge: 1, tabBarBadgeStyle: { backgroundColor: 'blue' }) // sample value
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work and I couldn't find any specific example on how to modify this colour, not in the docs nor anywhere else.

Is there any way to modify this colour?

**UPDATE**: My package versions are as follows:

`@react-navigation/bottom-tabs: ^5.11.1`

`react-native: 0.63.2`

`react: 16.13.1`

Comment: Are you on latest version of bottom tabs?

Comment: @satya164 I think you are referring to this line (taken from my package.json) `"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.2"`, which I think is indeed the latest version. I have edited the question to include version numbers.

Comment: Latest version is 5.11.1 https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs

Comment: @satya164 Ok, I upgraded to 5.11.1 but the problem still persists.

Comment: It works for me: https://snack.expo.io/pQD97pIBp Try clearning your metro cache https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#stale-cache-of-metro-bundler

Comment: @satya164 It worked! It seems that was indeed the problem. Thank you very much. I have answered my question stating the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @satya164, I was able to resolve the problem by clearing the metro bundler cache, via executing
`npx react-native start --reset-cache` as stated in the [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#stale-cache-of-metro-bundler) he provided.